# Populate array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have array like below:

```
"developers" : [ 
        "5bfe4059c8698b30183db389", 
        "5bfe406ec8698b30183db38a"
    ]
```

and it's model looks like below:

```
developers:{
    type: Array,
    ref: 'User',
    default:[]
  }
```

,

I want to populate it in mongodb. I tried .populate('developers') but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use aggregate

first you have to unwind the array

```
{
  $unwind:
    {
      path: <field path>,
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: <boolean>
    }
}
```

and after word you can use $loockup

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

the whole pipeline look like

```
db.getCollection('dates').aggregate([{
$unwind:'$developers'
},{
 $lookup:
         {
           from: 'users',
           localField: 'developers',
           foreignField:'id',
           as: 'info'
         }
}])
```

hope it will help